# PHP: show view icon if file pdf and show downloads icon if file doc

Tags: php

I want to show view icons if the file in pdf formate
and
want to show download cions if the file in doc formate
in pdf

Answer (score 0):

get extension of file

```php
$extension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

other code lines

```php
if($extension=='pdf')
{
   echo '<img src="download.png"/>';
}
if($extension=='doc')

{
    echo '<img src="optional"/>';
}
```